# How to toggle only the *next* .class or div (not the rest)

Tags: jquery, togglebutton

I was wondering how to toggle a "child" div only, clicking in a button which repeats over the html, like so :

```
<div class="button">
     <div class="hide toggle">
          Blah1
     </div>
</div>
<div class="button">
     <div class="hide toggle">
          Blah2
     </div>
</div>
<div class="button">
     <div class="hide toggle">
          Blah3
     </div>
</div>
```

The goal would be to affect only the inmediate child div, and keep hidden the rest.

I don't know if it's possible.

This bit of code was toggling me all of the divs :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

    $('.button').click(function() {
    $('.toggle').slideToggle();
    }, function () {
        $('.toggle').slideToggle();
    });

  });
</script>
```

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try

```
$(this).next('.toggle').slideToggle();
```

or

```
$(this).children('.toggle:first').slideToggle();
```

Answer (score 2):

Inside the click event handler the **this** keyword refers to the element that was clicked on. Replace your $('.toggle').slideToggle() lines with

```
$('.toggle',this).slideToggle();
```

Answer (score 1):

Thomas Stock and Russ Cam have it right... I just wrapped it up properly. Paste this onto your page somewhere... usually in the head or in the footer after all of your code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        $(".button").click(function() {
    $(this).next('.toggle').slideToggle();
    });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

what i have to do if my DIV that i want to toggle isn't child-element of the click-element, e.g:

```
<span onclick="$(this).next('.showme').slideToggle();">Klick to show first Showme-Class</span>
<div class="showme">You've clicked the first span-element</div>

<span onclick="$(this).next('.showme').slideToggle();">Klick to show second Showme-Class</span>
<div class="showme">You've clicked the second span-element</div>

<span onclick="$(this).next('.showme').slideToggle();">Klick to show third Showme-Class</span>
<div class="showme">You've clicked the third span-element</div>
```

Comment: hmm .. question or answer? If the former, please post a ... [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) :-)