# jQuery: Show next Class-Element when an element is clicked

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

I already found this threat: [How to toggle only the *next* .class or div (not the rest)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/911328/2987246)

But what I have to do if my Class that I want to toggle isn't a child-element of the click-element, e.g:

```
<span onclick="$(this).next('.showme').slideToggle();">Klick to show first Showme-Class</span>
<div class="showme">You've clicked the first span-element</div>

<span onclick="$(this).next('.showme').slideToggle();">Klick to show second Showme-Class</span>
<div class="showme">You've clicked the second span-element</div>

<span onclick="$(this).next('.showme').slideToggle();">Klick to show third Showme-Class</span>
<div class="showme">You've clicked the third span-element</div>
```

More specific:
In this example...

```
<div class="myclickclass">
<span onclick="this().next('.showme').slideToggle(100);">Click me</span>
<div class="showme">You've clicked</div>
</div>
```

the class "showme" is part (inside) of class "myclickclass".... jQuery works for me.

```
<div class="myclickclass">
<span onclick="this().next('.showme').slideToggle(100);">Click me</span>
</div>
<div class="showme">You've clicked</div>
```

In this example the class "showme" isn't part of my class "myclickclass". jQuery doesn't work for me.

Comment: If it _isn't a child-element of the click-element_, then what is it? It's parent? or in some other _div_? Please be a bit more specific...

Comment: you need to wrap all your elements in another parent div and use parent to navigate to next child div.

Comment: If you show us the relevant part of your html we can help :)

Comment: I've edited my post. I hope it's more specific - now ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
$(this).parent().next('.showme')
```

if it is not INSIDE.